# Using UIMA RUTA with Existing Taggers

Tags: nlp, uima, ruta, spotlight-dbpedia

I have recently started working with UIMA RUTA. I have a few questions. 
1: How can we use the existing taggers(DBpedia tagger, MunPx Tagger) in RUTA? 
2: How can we format the output using the Annotation Writer? 
3: Does RUTA takes other file formats apart from .txt as an input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1: How can we use the existing taggers(DBpedia tagger, MunPx Tagger) in RUTA?**

UIMA Ruta does not depend on a specific type system. If you have a pipeline with different taggers, and these tagger create annotations of some type system, then you can write rules using these annotations in a Ruta script and use these rules in an analysis engine in that pipeline. Dependent on the configuration, you maybe need to import the type system in your Ruta script.

**2: How can we format the output using the Annotation Writer?**

If you refer to the AnnoationWriter in ruta-core, then the answer is: you cannot format the output. You need to use a different analysis engine.

**3: Does RUTA takes other file formats apart from .txt as an input?**

In general Ruta processes the given CAS object, which is filled by any reader for any file format. In the UIMA Ruta Workbench, the launch configuration supports  ".txt", ".csv", "html", "xhtml" as plain text file formats and ".xmi", ".xcas", ".bcas", ".scas" using the SerialFormat detection of CasIOUtils.

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*